# determine current working program (task ) using C#

Tags: c#

i'm trying to develop C# app take an action when a specific program opened ( not only opened but need to be in use ) .
how can I determine is application now in use  ? (using C#)

for example : in  taskbar many programs are running ( calculator - Microsoft edge - visual studio - firefox ) 
how to determine what is the current application I use it now ?

Comment: Define "in use"?  If an application is running, then it's "in use"...there's no difference.

Comment: you can open 5 applications - all in running but you use now only one you use it right now

Comment: for example : now you use your web browser while other programs running in the same time .